# python : How to get the max value of dictionary keys in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello everyone lets say I have a list of values

```
shows = ['breaking.bad','mad.men','game.of.thrones','the.mandalorian']
```

I created a dictionary

```
d = defaultdict(list)


weekly_ratings = {
    5.0 : 'breaking.bad',
    4.0 : 'mad.men',
    4.6 : 'game.of.thrones',
    4.7 : 'the.mandalorian',
    2.5 : 'breaking.bad',
    3.5 : 'mad.men'
}

    for show in shows:
        for key, value in weekly_ratings.items():
            if any(show in v for v in value):
                d[show].append({key : value})
    new_d = dict(d)
    print(new_d)
    print(new_d['breaking.bad'])
```

this is my response for new_d

```
 {'breaking.bad': [{5.0: ('breaking.bad')}, {4.5: ('breaking.bad')}], 'mad.men': [{4.0: ('mad.men')}, {3.0: ('mad.men')}], 'game.of.thrones': [{4.5: ('game.of.thrones')}], 'the.mandalorian': [{4.0: ('the.mandalorian')}]}
```

here is the response I get for specific field for example `breaking bad`:

```
[{5.0: ('breaking.bad')}, {4.5 : ('breaking.bad')}]
```

what i want to achieve  is to get the highest key  of a specific field in the list of dictionaries in `new_d`

the expected output of a specific field(in this case breaking bad) : `5.0`

I have already tried `print(new_d['breaking.bad'][0][new_d.keys()])`

but i get the error:

```
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

Any pro tips or advice on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: `max(weekly_ratings)`?

Comment: @khelwood i do know of the `max` function but  If im looking for a specific field like breaking bad how to I get the max key of that field?

Comment: @khelwood also my dictionaries  are in a list

Comment: This looks like it'll be problematic after a few ratings; what if two shows receive the same rating, etc.? You're likely better off keying by-show and then having a list or dict of counts (perhaps by-time) or a custom object which can ingest a time-series (which is presumably how the original data arrives), providing a method to get the max rating, then finding the max of those max ratings per-show.

Comment: in which dictionary are you trying to find max `new_d` or `weekly_ratings`?

Comment: @deadshot new_d

Comment: can you post the valid `new_d` the one you printed is not valid

Comment: @deadshot hey deadshot I made the edits

Comment: @Malcode can you add the expected output. is it key inside the list or key in the dictionary?

Comment: @deadshot I made the edits again .  Also it would be the key inside the list , so If I go to breaking bad the expected output would be 5.0 as the highest key  in the list

Answer (score 1):

Going from OP's comment: "i do know of the max function but If im looking for a specific field like breaking bad how to I get the max key of that field?"

If you want to get the maximum key with a particular value, you can use `max` with a generator expression, like this:

```
max(k for (k,v) in weekly_ratings.items() if v=='breaking.bad')
```

Comment: There is no requirement in the question of v being equal to 'breaking_bad'

Comment: @Erick Not in the question, but in the OP's comments: "i do know of the max function but If im looking for a specific field like breaking bad how to I get the max key of that field?"

Comment: Right, I'll take it!

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

data = sorted(weekly_ratings.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
res = {k: max(g)[0] for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[1])}
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'breaking.bad': 5.0, 'game.of.thrones': 4.6, 'mad.men': 4.0, 'the.mandalorian': 4.7}
```

Using dict comprehension

```
res = {k: list(max(v, key=max).keys())[0] for k, v in new_d.items()}

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'breaking.bad': 5.0, 'mad.men': 4.0, 'game.of.thrones': 4.5, 'the.mandalorian': 4.0}
```

Comment: hey deadshot this  method works  so far but in the event I need the max value of the show `mad.men` what would I need to do in this case? this method appears that it would allow me to cherry pick as i please

Comment: thank you this works. I have have one last question in regards to this  question with your response I feel that i could have gotten  the `keys : highest value` earlier  in my for loop.  Would i have had to utilize  `list(max(v, key=max).keys()` while Im appending?

Comment: Sure  you can add different  keys  if you like. Actually  i will change them

Comment: hey deadshot for the dict comprehension can I default the  `v` to `0` ? lets say  game of thrones didnt appear that week the output would be `{'breaking.bad': 5.0, 'mad.men': 4.0, 'game.of.thrones': 0, 'the.mandalorian': 4.0}`. I was thinking about an if else within to  see if there is a response in `new_d` to print as per usual  else  ddfault to `0 : no weekly ratings`

Comment: No you can'd do that, first you need to find the missing values, then you can add that to the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, your dictionary must be set up the other way around, so the key would be the description while your value would be the weekly rating. Once you have the dictionary set up in this way, you get the key (description) with the maximum value (value) as:

```
max_rating_key = max(weekly_ratings, key=weekly_ratings.get)
```

If you still need to know the actual value just do:

```
max_rating = weekly_ratings[max_rating_key]
```

By the way, you can not have two values for a key in a dictionary as would be with the way you presented the data.
Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Try using max() function. I assume you want only the ratings value, right? You can use something like this:

```
x = max(weekly_ratings.keys())
print(x)
```

The keys() function will get the value of the key.

Comment: Thank you for responding  but I want to know   If im looking for a specific field like breaking bad how to I get the max key of that field that is in a list ?

Answer (score -1):

This sort of thing is much easier using set operations. The following shows how it can be done with Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

shows = ['breaking.bad','mad.men','game.of.thrones','the.mandalorian']

df_shows = pd.DataFrame({'title': shows})

df_ratings = pd.DataFrame( 
 [['breaking.bad',   5.0 ],
 ['mad.men',         4.0 ],
 ['game.of.thrones',     4.5 ],
 ['the.mandalorian',     4.0 ],
 ['breaking.bad',    4.5 ],
 ['mad.men' ,    3.5 ]], columns = ['title', 'rating'])  


top_rating_by_movie = ps.sqldf("""
    select  dfs.title, max(dfr.rating)  max_rating
    from df_shows dfs
     left join df_ratings dfr
      on dfr.title = dfs.title
    group by 1  """, locals())

print(top_rating_by_movie)
```

which results in the following:

```
             title  max_rating
0     breaking.bad         5.0
1  game.of.thrones         4.5
2          mad.men         4.0
3  the.mandalorian         4.0
```

Comment: who asked about pandas solution?